# Maven - Error code 401, Unauthorized

Tags: java, maven

I just imported some maven projects in my eclipse IDE.
But I have this error in the Eclipse projects:

```
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from https://intra.telecom.fr/CITnet/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of ecPublicRepository has elapsed or updates are forced. 
Original error: 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to ecPublicRepository
 (https://intra.telecom.fr/CITnet/nexus/content/groups/public/): 
Access denied to https://intra.telecom.fr/CITnet/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom. 
Error code 401, Unauthorized    pom.xml
```

But I have already defined the access to the site intra.telecom.fr
in the file C:\développement\apache-maven-3.0.5\conf\settings.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor
license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional
information regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file to
you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use
this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required
by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->

<!-- http://maven.apache.org/settings.html -->
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/settings/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<localRepository>C:/Users/joanet/.m2/repository</localRepository>


<proxies>
 <proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>joanet</username>
   <password>{yRso+k6+abkHTVcPc5esNgartpDSfHPWgHL/QvhQ33c=}</password>
  <host>168.168.141.12</host>
  <port>7022</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>localhost|intra.telecom.fr</nonProxyHosts>
 </proxy>
</proxies>

<servers>
  <server>
   <id>ecPublicRepository</id>
   <username>joanet</username>
   <password>{yRso+k6+abkHTVcPc5esNgartpDSfHPWgHL/QvhQ57c=}</password>
  </server>


</servers>

<mirrors></mirrors>

<pluginGroups>
 <!-- pluginGroup Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.  -->
 <pluginGroup>com.oracle.weblogic</pluginGroup>
 <pluginGroup>com.github.searls</pluginGroup>
 <pluginGroup>com.cj.jshintmojo</pluginGroup>
 <pluginGroup>com.github.phasebash</pluginGroup>

</pluginGroups>

<profiles>
 <profile>
  <id>activeProfile</id>

  <repositories>

   <repository>
      <id>ecPublicRepository</id>
      <url>https://intra.telecom.fr/CITnet/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
   </repository>


  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>

   <pluginRepository>
    <id>ecPublicRepository</id>
    <name>EC Public Repository</name>
    <url>https://intra.telecom.fr/CITnet/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
   </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

 </profile>

</profiles>

<!-- activeProfiles | List of profiles that are active for all builds. | -->
<activeProfiles>
 <activeProfile>activeProfile</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>


</settings>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are able to access intra.telecom.fr without proxy??

Comment: I would suggest creating a `settings.xml` file in `yourUserHomeDir/.m2` and adding all of your specific settings there instead of modifying the `settings.xml` that comes with Maven. Eclipse may be using a different Maven install. If you put customizations in `yourUserHomeDir/.m2/settings.xml` it's likely both Eclipse and other Maven installs will find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encrypt your master password using command and put it in `~/.m2/settings-security.xml`

```
mvn --encrypt-master-password  <your_master_pass>
```

Put encrypted master password into `~/.m2/settings-security.xml`.
For example, if you got string `{p123=}` content of file will be

```xml
<settingsSecurity>
  <master>{p123=}</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

Encrypt your password to Maven repository by running following command:
`mvn --encrypt-password <your_repo_pass>` and create `~/.m2/settings.xml` with following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <servers>
      <server>
        <id>id</id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>{hashed-passwd}</password>
      </server>
   </servers>
</settings>
```